# Is it possible to mix CUDA compute capabilities with two different gpus on a single system?

Tags: gpu, nvidia-graphics-card, cuda

OS is Debian 10. I currently have a Geforce 1060 GTX that I'm trying to use for various CUDA tasks. However, there is no way to "renice" a process that runs on a video card, so when my tasks are running I get major lag in x.org.

The apparent workaround is "get a 2nd gpu", so I am trying to do this. Currently looking at a K10, which suits almost all of my CUDA needs. (And the K10 is low enough power and has extra ram that makes it an ideal choice)

However, the K10 only has compute capability of 3.0. I have some other tasks that I would like to run that require a compute capability of 3.5, perhaps higher.

Before spending the money on the K10, I'm wondering, would this work? Would it be possible to run CUDA tasks on the K10 up to CC 3.0, and 1060 GTX up to CC 6.1 at the same time? Do the nvidia drivers cover this edge case? Seems like a rare scenario but I'm really hoping this is possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to bind a task to a given GPU by joggling the
[CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#env-vars)
environment variable before running the task.
You can use this variable to limit your application to run on a
single device or on a set of devices.

You may create a script that sets CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES to a
comma-separated list of device IDs, to make only those devices visible
to the application.

From the post
[How do I select which GPU to run a job on?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39649102/how-do-i-select-which-gpu-to-run-a-job-on)

> To specify CUDA device `1` for example, you would set the
> CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES using
>
> ```
> export CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES=1
> ```
>
> or
>
> ```
> CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES=1 ./cuda_executable
> ```
>
> The former sets the variable for the life of the current shell, the
> latter only for the lifespan of that particular executable invocation.
>
> If you want to specify more than one device, use
>
> ```
> export CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES=0,1
> ```
>
> or
>
> ```
> CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES=0,1 ./cuda_executable
> ```

So to answer your question :

> I'm wondering, would this work?

Answer : Yes, it would work, using CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES for
manually assigning tasks to their right GPU.

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly what I needed to know! Any sort of issues with the drivers also?

Comment: That's too general to answer. You would get better answers on the CUDA forums.